# Identifying what PowerMac I have

Tags: hardware, powerpc, classic-mac-os, power-mac

I'm having issues identifying what type of PowerMac G4 Quicksilver I have.

Looking at the stickers on the machine, I initially come to the conclusion that the machine is a `Power Macintosh G4 800 DP (Quicksilver)800 MHz PowerPC 7450 (G4) x2` (that's taken from everymac.com) however when going to `About This Mac` the machine shows it only has one processor, making me think its a `Power Macintosh G4 800 (QS 2002)800 MHz PowerPC 7455* (G4)`. The case itself has these two notes:

[image]
[image]

In the first of the two it is clear that the case is copyrighted 2001, but in the second it only seems to specify one processor. Since I got this machine second hand and don't know its history, I have considered the fact the logic board or the CPU board may have been replaced. Still I am not sure exactly what machine I have.

Why does all of this even matter? I want to be able to start the machine up with a universal OS9 install, however the 2002 Quicksilver apparently doesn't allow this, and has to be installed from original install discs. I have wheat I believe are the correct discs coincidentally, and OS9 installed fine, however hangs upon a successful boot, unless extensions are disabled.

I really don't know what this machine is, and how I can find out. I have not started up the Apple Hardware Test CD I also have, so if you'd like me to do so and maybe get some info from its report please do ask. I don't even know if it will start up. I'll update this once I have tested it.

Thank you for any replies.

Comment: Those 2 screws in the top picture don't look very 'Apple'. You could squeeze a wind-tunnel mobo & PSU into a quicksilver body, but only if it's a single CPU. That wind-tunnel PSU is too big to fit if it's a dual. The wind-tunnels had a recall on the PSU, so there were a lot of spares kicking around. [Info source - I had a dual 800 quicksilver + wind-tunnel PSU. I had to mount the PSU *externally*] Too long ago to remember more detail.

Comment: @tensujin [link](http://imgur.com/a/uarPF) logic board
[link](http://imgur.com/a/j95cE) In case
[link](http://imgur.com/a/yLmy5) PSU Sticker
[link](http://imgur.com/a/zquGT) Logic board sticker

Comment: Sorry - other than the rather obvious 'yup, that's a single CPU' ;) I'm afraid it's too long since I saw inside one to recognise it. I used to have the ADC disks from around that time which would have helped, but I have a feeling I decided to have a tidy up a couple of years ago :/

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help though in identifying its a single CPU

Comment: Ahh... good old iFixit - I found teardowns for both - maybe they'll help. [Quicksilver](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Power+Mac+G4+Quicksilver+Teardown/1465) & [MDD](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Powermac+G4+MDD+%28Mirrored+Drive+Doors%29+Teardown/1624) (wind tunnel). They do show I was wrong about those screw, too.

Comment: Does look like you have a quicksilver mobo - I can't tell on the PSU, though

Comment: @Tetsujin First one looks identical to my machine

Comment: ah, yup - step 32, wind tunnel PSU. Then I'd say you have a 'correct' if 'swapped for a single CPU' quicksilver.

Comment: Would this mean I have the 2001 or 2002 model? I'm assuming you mean I have the dual CPU 2001 model which has had its CPU replaced with a single CPU board right?

Comment: tbh, I can't hone it any closer; my experience is limited to just those 2 varieties. Didn't realise there were so many variations. fixit has one more teardown for comparison - https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Power_Mac_G4_M5183 but I don't even know which one that is on the Everymac list :/

Comment: Yea, that definitely isn't my machine.

Comment: Were you still wanting to narrow this down further, or are you happy with what you've identified with the help of @Tetsujin ?

Comment: @Monomeeth It'd be nice to narrow down exactly what machine I have, and what modifications it has. Then I can identify exactly what the machine is capable of.

Comment: @DevelopedLogic Let's have a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62841/identifying-what-power-mac-i-have).

Comment: @Monomeeth I would talk, but it won't let me, i need to be granted access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mac in question is a Power Macintosh G4 800 (QuickSilver 2002) model built in June 2002. In your case, it has the 800 MHz PowerPC 7455 G4 processor (as opposed to the PowerPC 7450 variant). This processor had a single core, but also had what Apple called an *[AltiVec Velocity Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltiVec)*.

The specific model details are: M8493 (EMC 1896) with model identifier PowerMac3,5.

In your question you mentioned Mac OS 9. This model is only officially capable of booting into Mac OS 9.2.2 (not an earlier version).

---

**You can check your serial number!**

Since posting this answer I remembered that everymac.com has a lookup function on their site that allows users to enter a serial number to identify their hardware. You can access this at: http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/

Comment: Very odd. It boots 9.2.1, but only successfully in no extension mode.

Comment: Well, sometimes what Apple says its Macs can do *officially* isn't what we find in real life. Just look at how many Macs support twice as much RAM as Apple says they will.

Comment: So I need to look for a model specific 9.2.2 disc right?

Comment: Yes. I do see them regularly available online, such as via eBay etc. There's also some great Classic Mac resources online too, from where you may find some useful info. For example: [1](https://www.macintoshrepository.org) and [2](http://macintoshgarden.org).